# winhttpcertcfg.exe unable to open pfx file

Tags: certificate, pfx, winhttpcertcfg

I have a PFX file that can be double clicked and imported with Certificate Import Wizard UI (Crypto Shell Extensions). However, when I use winhttpcertcfg.exe from command line as following:

winhttpcertcfg.exe -i myfile.pfx -c LOCAL_MACHINE\MY -a myaccount -p mypassword

It always gives an error saying "Unable to open PFX file".

winhttpcertcfg.exe seems to be working fine at retrieving installed certs from cert store but just wounldn't import my pfx file.

Any idea where I might be doing wrong here?
Thanks!